# Safari on Catalina not loading PDF

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, safari, adobe-reader, macos-catalina

Using Safari 14.0.1 on Catalina 10.15.7, I'm unable to [view a certain PDF](https://www.experian.com/content/dam/marketing/na/automotive/quarterly-webinars/credit-trends/q3-2020-safm.pdf).

Safari loads a black screen with a "Blocked Plug-in" message in the middle.

Other PDFs, [such as this one](http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf), will load just fine.

Earlier I noticed that I had Adobe Acrobat Reader DC installed. I used the [Acrobat Cleaner Tool](https://labs.adobe.com/downloads/acrobatcleaner.html) to remove it from my system.

[Others are also having the same problem](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251891851) but no solution has been found yet. Any idea how to force Safari to use it's own internal PDF rendering engine?

Answer (score 0):

I happened across this issue today with MacOS 11.2.3 and Safari 14.0.3. The solution for me was to find a PDF in the Finder and "get info" on it using the system menu.

Once I did that I selected "Preview" again as the default app viewer and then clicked "Change All...".

Once I did this and reloaded the PDF in the browser it displayed using the default Preview app and no more Plug-in Blocked.

Hope this helps